# Changing img's src and fadin works no so well in FF

Tags: jquery, firefox, fade

I made a bit of code who fades out an image, change the `src` attribute, then `fadeIn()` the new image.
This works fine in Chrome, but not in FireFox.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
var myInterval=setInterval(function(){myChanging()},5000);

function myChanging () {
    var newUrl = urlBaseBackground + currentIndex + ".jpg";
    var image = jQuery('#bckimg');
    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    image.attr('src', newUrl);
                    image.fadeIn(1000);
                });
    currentIndex ++;
    if (currentIndex > totalCountBackgroundImages-1)
        currentIndex = 0;
}
```

In the body :

```
 <img id="bckimg" 
      style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:-1;" 
      src="/back/0.jpg" />
```

FF changes the image when it is displayed, not between the fadein and out.
I tried a setTimeout before the `'.attr("src"...'` part but it didn't work either.

Any clue anyone ?

EDIT : forgot to mention that I load all images with another function before launching the fades.

Comment: @Nandu There is really no reason for the bold editing you seem to do in various edits. Please, see [Is editing posts to only introduce bold emphasis acceptable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158564/169503).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make a chained action:

```
image.fadeOut(1000).attr('src', newUrl).fadeIn(1000);
```

Or try the [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) function:

```
 image.fadeOut(1000);
 image.promise().done(function()
 {
    $(this).attr('src', newUrl).fadeIn(1000);
 });
```

Comment: Things got worse ... doesn't work on Chrome now ^^
You can watch on http://nakama-it.net/excelsus/

Comment: There is still some glitches, just in FF.
I deactivated a plugin who makes annoucement vith FX effects.
Is it possible that the number of tabs open in FF affects the behaviour of fading effects ?

Comment: Maybe, because in your site I see it perfect in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Ok, I'll let like this, hoping that other visitors will not have a FF on Ubuntu and a better computer than mine ;) Thanks for your time Ronen.